# java: any way to detect changes in display configuration?

Tags: java, swing

One of my coworkers would like my Swing app to adapt correctly to the removal of a 2nd display monitor.

Is there any way to get notification of this, other than polling to repeatedly compute virtual bounds? (per the code sample in http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html)

Answer (score 3):

Hum, tricky one. Because GraphicsConfiguration class won't give us any listeners, I'll have only a couple of alternatives:

1. (If Windows) Use a JNI interface to
   Windows to detect display settings
   change and forward them to Java.
   This would be the
   SystemEvents::DisplaySettingsChanged
   Event.
2. Create a simple polling Thread -
   timer that retrieves the result of
   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
   as you've already stated before.